# Android Starter Project Structure

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio

I'm starting with android studio and I was trying that the application check the connectivity before to start, for this I'm creating an splash screen, but I really don't find the way to calculate the time for checking the connectivity, my requirement is that the splash screen only stay visible while I'm checking the connectivity.
This is what I have in my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int myTimer = 4000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, DashBoard.class);
            boolean result = AppManager.CheckConnectionStatus(getApplicationContext());
            if(result == true) {
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                //Show a Message informing there is not internet connection
            }

            finish();
        }
    }, myTimer);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}
```

As you can see I'm waiting 4000 ms but this is not the idea...
If any have any idea of how can I face this I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand, you want to check network availability and then if available go start MainActivity. You can check network availability with this function:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
{
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then add this codes on your SplashScreen activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, DashBoard.class);

    if(isInternetAvailable(Splash.this)){
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Splash.this, 
            "Please check your internet options...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add this permissions to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I wish i could understand you right. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AsyncTask` in this case. Here's some simple code to get you started:

```
public class CheckConnectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Display some waiting progress bar or a splash image here
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return AppManager.CheckConnectionStatus(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        if (result) {
            // start next activity
        } else {
            // error message that you're not connected.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much I will try your example it seems very useful for a lot of things in my application, I appreciate your help a lot.